# Rudin Principle of analysis Ex 3.4

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm trying to solve the practice problems in Rudin and I am stuck on Exercise 3.4.

As follows: [image]

Writing out the terms of the sequence for $\{s_n\}$, I had guessed the solution but how does one obtain the sequence right from the beginning ? Now that I see the terms for the sequence, it isnt so hard but how does one figure this out a formula though ?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just derive the recursion for the even-indexed sequence elements,
$$
s_{2m+2}=\frac{s_{2m+1}}2=\frac14+\frac{s_{2m}}2.
$$
Subtract $\frac12$ to get the geometric recursion
$$
s_{2m+2}-\frac12=\frac12\left(s_{2m}-\frac12\right).
$$